# Singularity of complex function $\frac{ \sin\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{z}}$ at zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

How to check singularity of complex function $\frac{ \sin\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{z}} $at zero(  Here $\sqrt{z}$ is principal square root function )?.I think it’s limit at zero is not equal to 1 as here zero is not isolated singularity . So it’s not a removable singularity and hence non isolated singularity . Am I correct ? Please suggest me . Thanks

Comment: What's its Laurent series?

Comment: Laurent series is again for isolated singularity....

Comment: Lord shark the Unknown please suggest me in explicit form

Comment: This function is not well-defined. Without more context, $\sqrt{z}$ is meaningless.

Comment: Here $\sqrt{z}$ is principal square root function .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D=\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ be the domain of the principal branch of $\sqrt z$. The function is clearly analytic on $D$. If $z\in D$ and $n\in\Bbb N$, then $(\sqrt z)^{2n}=z^n$ and $(\sqrt z)^{2n+1}=z^n\,\sqrt z$. Thus
$$
\sin(\sqrt z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2\,n+1)!}\,(\sqrt z)^{2n+1}=\sqrt z\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2\,n+1)!}\,z^n
$$
and
$$
\frac{\sin(\sqrt z)}{\sqrt z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2\,n+1)!}\,z^n,\quad z\in D.
$$
Since this series defines an entire function, we may extend $\frac{\sin(\sqrt z)}{\sqrt z}$ to all of $\Bbb C$ in such a way that it is analytic everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much sir ...